# Autohotkey, use F1 as prefix key but do NOT block Ctrl+F1, Shift+F1 etc

Tags: autohotkey

Using the following statement,

```
F1 & F9:: Msgbox, Got F1+F9
```

I can successfully use F1 as a prefix hotkey, quite a useful feature. However, I quickly find that <kbd>Ctrl+F1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+F1</kbd> etc lose their functionality, i.e. application cannot detect them.

I tried to add a tilde,

```
～F1 & F9:: Msgbox, Got F1+F9
```

but this always trigger <kbd>F1</kbd> for application before I have the chance to press <kbd>F9</kbd> -- not what I want.

How to achieve the desired result?

BTW: I can totally accept the minor side effect of firing F1, Ctrl+F1 or Shift+F1 when <kbd>F1</kbd> is *released*.

Autohotkey 1.1.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out myself.

```
F1 & F9:: MsgBox, F1+F9

*F1 up:: Send {Blind}{F1 down}{F1 up}
```

The `{Blind}` is important. Without it, pressing <kbd>Shift+F1</kbd> will(may) cause application to get only <kbd>F1</kbd>. In my actual case, my application is EmEditor v14, and I have successfully achieve:

- **F1+F9** or **F1+F10** to quickly switch between first row tabs.
- **F2+F9** or **F2+F10** to quickly switch between second row tabs.
- **F3+F9** or **F3+F10** to quickly switch between third row tabs.
- **F4+F9** or **F4+F10** to quickly switch between fourth row tabs.
- use **F5+...* if desired

I do this because EmEditor, although great at many other aspects, does not provide a quick way to switch document tabs by keyboard.

If you're interested, I can post my whole script later, about 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
F1 Up::
  Hotkey,F1 & F9,On
  MsgBox,up
return

F1 & F9::
  Hotkey,F1 & F9,Off
  MsgBox,F1 & F9
return
```

Comment: Your script has two problems. (1) It blocks application from getting Shift+F1, Ctrl+F1 etc. (2) In the case of pressing F1+F9, application should not get F1 when F1 is released, while your code violates this.